# How should I address this crashing problem?

Tags: android, crash, out-of-memory, spinner, dropdown

I recently created an android application, and after I completely redid my spinner dropdown menus using a custom adapter, some devices are crashing.  It's very minimal, like 3 people have experienced crashes ever, but still it's something I want to address if possible because the apps minimum SDK version is as low as 16, so I imagine it's older devices that struggle the most.  Attached is a pic of the crash report!  This specific device has 2 GB of memory, you would think that would easily be enough to load a spinner with a bunch of low quality images right?

Thanks for the help in advance!  This is the crash report:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQRk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory the device has != the amount of memory you can use.  The OS takes a lot.  Other apps take a good amount.  And even the memory you can use is fragmented into different pools.  Generally "OutOfMemoryException" means out of Java heap memory (out of native memory would be a different crash, for example).  Bitmap memory goes into different buckets on different OS versions, they've changed it a few times.  So it could be a variety of reasons-  you have too large an image that's using insane memory, your have leaks, you have sufficient memory on the device but the heap allocation spiked for some reason, your network layer isn't efficient (if you use Volley to download images its particularly stupid about that).  There's not enough info here to actually give you a suggestion.  I'd try to replicate it on a simulator with the RAM purposely capped at 1GB or smaller and see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks, I think you pointed me in the right direction and from there I did some tests and solved all my problems.